# Is it possible to search in multiple tables using Lucene.Net?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, lucene, lucene.net

I am making a search engine in VisualStudio 2013. I am using Lucene.Net and I am wondering if it is possible to search in multiple tables within the database i have. I know how to search in multiple fields within a table, but I need to be able to search in multiple tables as well.
Is this possible in any way?

Comment: Err... What's a *table* in Lucene?

Comment: I mean in the databases table.

Comment: The point is, lucene has no concept of a "table".  I guess the answer, then, would be "yes".  It will probably be trivial to accomplish, really. But it's just not clear what searching multiple tables means to you, and with regards to your usage of Lucene.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible. The implementation will likely be unique to your needs so I cannot really help give you code to get started. Lucene uses the concept of documents, the structure of which is completely up to you. The more information you choose to store in those documents, the slower your search and indexing operations will be.

What you want to do is figure out what information users need to be able to search by, and what information you need to fetch relevant database information based upon those indexed fields. For example, you might index the title of a document or some/all of its body. If you query against those fields, then you will want to other information, likely table key values, that will allow you to fetch information relevant to that search. For example, you could store info to allow the fetching of related articles, or comments on the document, etc.

I hope that clears up how Lucene can be used, unfortunately the implementation details for your application are likely too specific to give more detailed answers.